# How restore postgreSQL dump file using pgAdmin?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I've a .dmp file. Want to restore the database from it. Using pgAdmin how can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761073/how-to-restore-postgresql-dump-file-into-postgres-databases

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Within PgAdmin3...

- Create a new database within the server you are using.
- Right click this database and choose 'Restore'.
- Use the 'Browser' button to select your '.dmp' file.
- Select 'Restore' to start restoring the database.

Comment: doesn't support '.dmp' file. I cant restore '.backup' files, but not '.dmp'

Comment: How did you create the .dmp file?

Comment: I'd just give it a try through PgAdmin - you'll probably find they're created a compressed backup (.backup file) but just named it as a .dmp file instead.

Comment: @fatCop to upload .dump files select all files in select list at right buttom