# When i recover data from backup file in existing database then come duplicate data ( postgreSQL database)

Tags: postgresql

I run this command

```
pg_dump mydatabase > backupfile
```

and after that delete some record from table in mydatabase and then run

```
psql mydatabase < backupfile
```

then in table occurred  **data redundancy problem**.

Comment: use `--clean` in restore script !, Read the Postgres document : - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgrestore.html#APP-PGRESTORE-OPTIONS

Comment: There are plenty of answers available for your question here is one of them : - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761073/how-to-restore-postgresql-dump-file-into-postgres-databases

Comment: What is your actual need?, what you want to do with the backup file ?

Comment: I have some data in my database and I want to add some new related data from backup file, and I don't want redundancy in my database and want the distinct values.                                                                                                       e.g. I have 5 entries in my 'database'  that are........... '1',, '3', '4', '5', '6'......................... and in backup file there are 3 entries '1', '2', '3'........... and i want merge the both.......... and want result like, '1', '2','3', '4','5','6'................ please help

Comment: what comes to my mind is leave the actual DB as it is. Now create a new DB and restore your backup.So you can use  `dbblink()` function to get values from one db from another, Using `dbblink()` you can get(`select`) desired value from restored DB and insert it to the actual DB or use `COPY` method to import desired rows as `.csv` file  from backuped DB and export it to actual DB

Comment: I'd use foreign data wrappers not dblink, but otherwise yes, that's the way to go.

Comment: foreign data wrappers but how ?????